# Messages app do not recognize my deep links schemas

Tags: android

I'm implementing a share feature in my app, the user will be able to share a deep link via sms or any other message app. 
The issue I'm facing is that the Phone's message app does not recognize the generated deep link as a link.

I have on the manifest file the intent filter with the scheme and host declared. Also I was able test the deep link from a push notification, that means the manifest configuration works. However, I can't tap the message app deep link and open my app.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.DailyGiveawayActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="${schemeBU}${schemeEnv}"
                tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError" />
            <data
                android:host="GiveawayRegistration"
                tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Post a sample of your link. (same as the one you are clicking on your sms app).

Comment: Generated links looks like the following: LaunchCEDev://GiveawayRegistration?q=22222.

Comment: add a dot something to your host name in manifest and try again (e.g: GiveawayRegistration.com instead of just GiveawayRegistration)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue using the Android App Link API.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html.

Using the fallowing intent filter my code is working and the OS knows how to handle the generated URL (even when doesn't exist). The OS will prompt a dialog, the user will  have to pick an app capable to manage this url (browsers and my app), but that is good for now. Next stage will be eliminate this steep.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="${schemeBU}${schemeEnv}"
                android:pathPattern="/Register" />
        </intent-filter>
```